# CORS errors when logging ITFoxtec

Tags: c#, cors, saml-2.0, asp.net-core-3.1, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I'm trying to use ITFoxtec to login SAML2 using backend .net core (port 5000) and angular client (port 4200). Note that Both have different ports.
When I call the controller Login method from Angular Client to read the SAML config and redirect(302) the request to my identity server to login (as the example https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/tree/master/src/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.MvcCore), I'm having cors issues.
Is this error because the requested server doesn´t have cors enabled? I've tested it with blazor where the backend and client are the same ports and it works fine. Any help? Thanks!

[error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZYDx.png)

Comment: CORS requests only apply to browsers.  Blazor requests originate from your server, not the users browser.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but once it has been called by the server, how Chrome can record this call on the network tab?

Comment: It won't, the request wasn't made by the browser.

Comment: ITfoxtec Identity SAML2 only support server based login and not JS client based like an Angular Client. You need to handle the login flow in the backend and use another mechanism to secure the JS client.

Comment: I really don't understand how the user will type the credentials with the login flow in the backend once the idp needs to open the browser for that.